# How to get nested elements in Google App script / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to get values `{nb_conversions":58"}` under `idgoal=ecommerceAbandonedCart, idgoal=4` and so on , I have tried different ways but unsuccessful, would appreciate it if someone can quickly sort this out for me.

Here is API URL: https://demo.matomo.cloud/?module=API&method=UserCountry.getRegion&idSite=1&period=day&date=yesterday&format=JSON&token_auth=anonymous

Sample Data:
`[{"label":"Unknown","nb_uniq_visitors":558,"nb_visits":590,"nb_actions":980,"nb_users":0,"max_actions":14,"sum_visit_length":76439,"bounce_count":408,"nb_visits_converted":45,"goals":{"idgoal=ecommerceAbandonedCart":{"nb_conversions":58,"nb_visits_converted":58,"revenue":16199.299999999997,"items":88},"idgoal=ecommerceOrder":{"nb_conversions":10,"nb_visits_converted":10,"revenue":606.7,"revenue_subtotal":2448,"revenue_tax":0,"revenue_shipping":0,"revenue_discount":22.45,"items":12},"idgoal=4":{"nb_conversions":2,"nb_visits_converted":2,"revenue":2},"idgoal=5":{"nb_conversions":1,"nb_visits_converted":1,"revenue":5},"idgoal=6":{"nb_conversions":2,"nb_visits_converted":2,"revenue":4},"idgoal=7":{"nb_conversions":16,"nb_visits_converted":16,"revenue":16},"idgoal=8":{"nb_conversions":13,"nb_visits_converted":13,"revenue":0},"idgoal=10":{"nb_conversions":1,"nb_visits_converted":1,"revenue":0}},"nb_conversions":45,"revenue":633.7,"region":"xx","country":"xx","country_name":"Unknown","region_name":"Unknown","logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/flags\/xx.png"}]`

```
    function Goals() {
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Goals");
  
  
  
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  
  var today = sheet.getRange(1,6).getValue().toDateString();
  
  var startDate = sheet.getRange(lastRow,1).getValue();
  
  var now = sheet.getRange(lastRow,1).getValue().toDateString();
  
  var dt = new Date(startDate);
  
  //Logger.log(now);
 // Logger.log(today);
  //Logger.log(dt);
  
   
  if( today != now){
    
       
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://demo.matomo.cloud/?module=API&method=UserCountry.getRegion&idSite=1&period=day&date=yesterday&format=JSON&token_auth=anonymous");
  var json=response.getContentText();
  var dataSet=JSON.parse(json);
  
     
  for(var i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++)
    {
      sheet.getRange(i+lastRow+1,2).setValue([dataSet[i]['label']]);
      sheet.getRange(i+lastRow+1,3).setValue([dataSet[i]['nb_visits']]);
      sheet.getRange(i+lastRow+1,4).setValue([dataSet[i]['nb_uniq_visitors']]);
      sheet.getRange(i+lastRow+1,5).setValue([dataSet[i]['goals']['idgoal=ecommerceAbandonedCart']]);
      sheet.getRange(i+lastRow+1,1).setValue(now);
    }
    
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1);
  lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1).setValue(dt);
  }


}
```

Comment: The `UrlFetchApp.fetch` parameter has a syntax error, the URL should be quote enclosed.

Comment: Thanks, its corrected @Rubén

Answer (score 1):

Given your sample data, try fetching the keys using `Object.keys()` and loop them one by one to get all `nb_conversions` instead of passing the `idgoal`s individually. See below:

#### Code:

```
var dataSet = [{"label":"Unknown","nb_uniq_visitors":558,"nb_visits":590,"nb_actions":980,"nb_users":0,"max_actions":14,"sum_visit_length":76439,"bounce_count":408,"nb_visits_converted":45,"goals":{"idgoal=ecommerceAbandonedCart":{"nb_conversions":58,"nb_visits_converted":58,"revenue":16199.299999999997,"items":88},"idgoal=ecommerceOrder":{"nb_conversions":10,"nb_visits_converted":10,"revenue":606.7,"revenue_subtotal":2448,"revenue_tax":0,"revenue_shipping":0,"revenue_discount":22.45,"items":12},"idgoal=4":{"nb_conversions":2,"nb_visits_converted":2,"revenue":2},"idgoal=5":{"nb_conversions":1,"nb_visits_converted":1,"revenue":5},"idgoal=6":{"nb_conversions":2,"nb_visits_converted":2,"revenue":4},"idgoal=7":{"nb_conversions":16,"nb_visits_converted":16,"revenue":16},"idgoal=8":{"nb_conversions":13,"nb_visits_converted":13,"revenue":0},"idgoal=10":{"nb_conversions":1,"nb_visits_converted":1,"revenue":0}},"nb_conversions":45,"revenue":633.7,"region":"xx","country":"xx","country_name":"Unknown","region_name":"Unknown","logo":"plugins\/Morpheus\/icons\/dist\/flags\/xx.png"}];

for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
  // Upon testing your linked data, some of them doesn't have goals key. 
  // Be sure to only access those who have goals to avoid encountering an error.
  if(dataSet[i]['goals']) {
    Object.keys(dataSet[i]['goals']).forEach(function (idgoal){
      Logger.log(dataSet[i]['goals'][idgoal]['nb_conversions']);
    });
  }
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- I recommend you format the data or view it in a site like [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) one. It really helps a lot.
- The `nb_conversions` being fetched above are only the ones under the `goals` key.
- If some `idgoals` doesnt have `nb_conversions`, just skip them like in `goals` above. The linked data above all has `nb_conversions` so I didn't include them for now.

#### References

- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)